# Addition program with size limit

Tags: c, embedded, 8051

I'm trying to write a code in C (Using Keil µVision 5, device: AT89C51AC3) that lets me enter 2 Integer numbers, add them and then print them out. The problem is that I'm limited to a byte code size of max. 2048.

My actual code needs 2099 Bytes to run.

Any idea how I could do the same thing using less memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <REG52.H> 

int main()
{
   int a, b;


    /*------------------------------------------------
    Setup the serial port for 1200 baud at 16MHz.
    ------------------------------------------------*/
    #ifndef MONITOR51
        SCON  = 0x50;               /* SCON: mode 1, 8-bit UART, enable rcvr      */
        TMOD |= 0x20;               /* TMOD: timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload        */
        TH1   = 221;                /* TH1:  reload value for 1200 baud @ 16MHz   */
        TR1   = 1;                  /* TR1:  timer 1 run                          */
        TI    = 1;                  /* TI:   set TI to send first char of UART    */
    #endif

   printf("Enter 2 numbers\n");
   scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

   printf("%d\n",a+b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your target platform? What input devices do you have? What is the output device? Can you read directly from the input-device without using the standard C `scanf` function? Can you output directly to the output-device the same way?

Comment: Maybe not using `scanf` and `printf`?

Comment: @xMarcoGP: The standard `printf` and `scanf` functions are very flexible and generic, hence resource hungry. Try replacing them with hand-written bare-bones integer conversion and printing functions.

Comment: So you need to "squeeze" the code. A candidate is to replace `scanf` with your own code for simple parsing of two numbers.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Some 8051 variant with a UART for stdio by the looks of it. Hopefully the default `getchar`/`putchar` functions route there at least.

Comment: I'm using Keil µVision 5, my device is "AT89C51AC3", any idea? I'm not an expert, what alternatives are there? I need to enter the numbers in the console, and output them to the screen using a UART

Comment: @xMarcoGP: Well, purchasing a compiler license springs to mind. Or switching to IAR where the demo program size limit is 4k. Or hand optimizing the code.

Comment: @doynax I got it, I need to optimize the code. The question is how.

Comment: The problem is not the compiler, but the use of stdio.h. Also, why would anyone use 8051 in the year 2017?

Comment: @Lundin: Masocism. Plus there's an unfortunate number silicon vendors still pumping them out, unfortunately, along with old hardware to maintain :(

Comment: @Lundin Probably because it is simple to program for, and therefore used in schools for teaching the basics of both assembler programming, hardware-specific programming and the basics of how computers work "under the hood".

Comment: @Some programmer dude: I beg to differ. The 8051 architecture is deeply byzantine and a special flower in almost all respects. Writing efficient C and even assembly for non-trivial applications using these beasts is a real mess. Believe me, I've been there :(

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exactly, that's my situation. I have to use this "8051", and I sincerely have no idea how I could optimize the code.. thanks anyway for the help and suggestions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 8 bit microcontrollers in general, and 8051 in particular, are rather hard to program in C. At least if you look at the generated disassembly. A modern ARM Cortex M is much easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hiccup when you see this simple code take up 2k+ of memory. That's a lot! The reason for this is that the stdio functions are terribly inefficient.

If you need to save memory and execution speed, you need to code these yourself. Which is not so hard, since you probably just need to read integers and not everything else those function can handle (float numbers, strings etc).

Also get rid of the `int` type, use the fixed size types from `stdint.h` instead. (If this is a 8 bit MCU, you should also avoid 16 bit numbers unless they are necessary.)

In addition, you will have to code the I/O part as well. On a microcontroller this would probably mean writing your own UART driver.

You should be able to reduce the code size to a couple of hundred bytes, depending on how code (in)efficient your microcontroller is.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to print the sum of int a and int b, you should be able to get rid of the

/*------------------------------------------------
    Setup the serial port for 1200 baud at 16MHz.
    ------------------------------------------------*/
    #ifndef MONITOR51
        SCON  = 0x50;               /* SCON: mode 1, 8-bit UART, enable rcvr      */
        TMOD |= 0x20;               /* TMOD: timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload        */
        TH1   = 221;                /* TH1:  reload value for 1200 baud @ 16MHz   */
        TR1   = 1;                  /* TR1:  timer 1 run                          */
        TI    = 1;                  /* TI:   set TI to send first char of UART    */
    #endif:
`

code. Just keep the printf()... and scarf()... functions.

Comment: And how exactly are printf/scanf going to work without an initialized UART? This is a microcontroller.